# Proving a set is Lebesgue Measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Measure is a serious weak point of mine, and I cannot figure out this problem:

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable. Suppose that for all open intervals $I$, we have $m(E\cap I) \leq \frac{1}{2} m(I)$, where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure. Prove that $m(E)=0$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Man, I thought I had searched thoroughly but I guess not! Thanks! I'll delete this post shortly.

Comment: You don't have to delete this post because it should allow as many answer as possible.

Answer (score 2):

We can assume that $m(E)<\infty$ by first considering the sets $E\cap[n,n+1]$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, which would satisfy the same properties. Suppose on the contrary that $m(E) = \alpha>0$. Then there exists an open set $V$ (which we could write as a countable union of disjoint intervals $V = \cup{I_k}$) such that $E\subset V$ and $m(V) < 2\alpha$. Now
$$ m(E) = m(E\cap V) = m(E\cap(\cup{I_k})) = m(\cup{(E\cap I_k)}) = \sum{m(E\cap I_k)}.$$
Derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Since $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, there exists pairwise disjoint interval $I_i$ such that
$$
E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i\quad\text{ and }\quad m(E)=\inf{ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} m(I_i)}\tag{1}
$$
Since
$$
\quad E=E\cap\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} (E\cap I_i)
$$
By Lebesgue measure
$$
m(E)\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} m(E\cap I_i)\leqslant \frac1{2}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}m(I_i)
$$
By (1), we have
$$
m(E)\leqslant \frac1{2}m(E)
$$
Thus  $m(E)=0$.